# How to create context menu by using C# on WP SL8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Two questions about context menu:
1) How to create a context menu by using c#, not in xaml?
2) If I don't want to use Siverlight for WP toolkit, is there have other way to implement context menu?

Comment: Are you looking for [ListPickerFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listpickerflyout.aspx) or [ComboBox](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/05/22/Migrating-from-the-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-ListPicker-to-the-new-XAML-ComboBox-(Display-a-ListPicker-in-XAML-apps).aspx)?

Comment: ListPicker is for runtime apps only, a ComboBox is a different thing from what he is asking for

Comment: @fillobotto The OP mislead me with *'I don't want to use Siverlight'*, for runtime [MenuFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308516.aspx) would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the second question, the answer is no, you have to uae the Toolkit.

This is an article that explains how to launch a ContextMenu programmatically: http://metronuggets.com/2013/06/17/launching-a-context-menu-from-code/

Comment: Why I'm looking for a substitute for context menu, it's because context menu in my Xaml code always raise a boring crash occurring from time to time, and I think it's SL for WP toolkit's bug. Very thanks for your solution, I create a ContextMenu programmatically, now my problem is gone. :-)

Comment: Glad to help, but I invite you to revise your code since I used toolkit's ContextMenu declaring it in XAML without problems for over an year